# How to convert a function from Matlab to python?

Tags: function

I'm trying to convert a big function from Matlab to Python. The function starts like this.

```
function net = ANN_AP(X,T,OutputName)
```

I used `def net = ANN_AP(X,T,OutputName):` but an error of syntax appears.

Any helps?

Answer (score 0):

In python the values a function returns are defined when you call `return` rather than in the `def` line. So `return net` at the end would do what you want. This allows you to return different outputs or even different numbers of outputs depending on the scenario, something more difficult to do in MATLAB.  So

```
function net = ANN_AP(X,T,OutputName)
    do something
end
```

Is equivalent to:

```
def ANN_AP(X, T, OutputName):
    do something
    return net
```